# The row doesn't belong to the same DataSet as this relation

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
DataSet customerOrders = new DataSet();
DataSet.CustomersDataTable customers = new DataSet.CustomersDataTable();
CustomersTableAdapter adapter = new CustomersTableAdapter();
adapter.Fill(customers);

DataSet.OrdersDataTable orders = new DataSet.OrdersDataTable();
OrdersTableAdapter oAdapter = new OrdersTableAdapter();
oAdapter.Fill(orders);

DataRelation relation = (DataRelation)customerOrders.Relations[0];


foreach (DataRow row in customers.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow orderRow in row.GetChildRows(relation))
    {
        Response.Write(orderRow["OrderID"].ToString());
    }
}
```

I get this exception : The row doesn't belong to the same DataSet as this relation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a doubt. What is the purpose of 'foreach (DataRow orderRow in row.GetChildRows(relation))' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **customers** `DataTable` doesn't belong to **customerOrders** `DataSet`.

You must change this fragment of code

```
DataSet.CustomersDataTable customers = new DataSet.CustomersDataTable();
```

by this

```
DataSet.CustomersDataTable customers = customerOrders.Tables.Add("Customers");
```